# GitHub for Mac app memory expansion freezes GitHub app

Tags: macos, git, memory, github, github-for-mac

When I try to launch GitHub for Mac it immediately starts using up all of the free memory (as much as 1.6 Gb) until the application freezes.  How can I limit the memory usage for this app?

I saw a previous stackoverflow post (titled 'Memory Issues for Mac App') that touched on this issue, and I've updated my .gitconfig file, but it isn't having any effect.  It's not clear if if the app is even reading the config file or how it would be possible to determine whether it is or not.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion for git is to use it from the command line. It was designed for use from the command line. By not using it from the command line, you lose the following:

- command history
- scriptability
- piping
- tab-completion
- lots of help and examples online

The first is a big one. You will ask yourself "What did I do to create a branch with tracking of another one?". On the command line you can hit `ctrl-R` and type "branch". Hit `ctrl-R` a few more times to iterate over each occasion that you used `git branch`. You will find what you did when you made that branch. Pressing up and down arrows will scroll you through previous and subsequent commands that you issued. You can even add the time and date into history and when you list the history you can see exactly when you did something.

Scripts are very useful for things you do repeatedly and the same tasks are tedious when done manually through the gui.

Piping is very useful as you can alter results from one command and pass them to another. Something I do quite often is

```
git branch | 
   grep 'filter for what I need' | 
   sed 'some funky transformation' |
   xargs -n 1 -i{} git push -u centralrepo {}:public/{}
```

It's a made up example of how you might string together a few commands to automate some very time consuming task.

Tab-completion is great as it saves you time for having to hunt around for what branch exists or what file exists. It is context sensitive so when git expects a file to be listed, tab will fall through and start matching files underneath. When it's expecting a remote name, hitting tab a couple of times will get you a list of remote repositories. Partially typed branches or files or remote will get you a subset when you hit tab twice.

Getting help with git is important. It's got a steep learning curve. The majority of git's use is from the command line. So when you run into issues, google is very good at finding a solution quickly. Other git tools don't have this luxury and you may find yourself wasting quite a lot of time to find answers.

Comment: Yup. I was just starting to come to that conclusion.

Comment: I want to point out that although this answer is generally helpful, it does not actually answer this specific question.